# DBMS: stuck on function

Tags: function

I'm trying to write a trigger for a database but feel a bit lost. This is what I want the trigger to do: When there have been changes made to shipments (so when a new item has been shipped) I want to alter the value stock in another relation also called stock by subtracting 1, so that the two relationships correlate.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: the only thing i notice out of the ordinary would be this should probably be a before insert instead of an after. but with that being said i think more information is needed for us to help

can you provide an example of what is happening, and then an example of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `old` and `new` items refer to to the `shipment` table. Since the stock fields are in the `stock` table, you need to explicitly update it. Similarly, you will want to fetch the count and assess its validity.

```
CREATE FUNCTION decstock() RETURNS trigger as $pname$
    qty integer;

    BEGIN
      --Get the current count
      SELECT stk.stock 
      INTO qty 
      FROM stock stk 
      WHERE stk.isbn=old.isbn;

      --Validate count
      IF (qty = 0) then
           raise exception 'There is no stock to ship';
      ELSE
          --Update valid stock
          UPDATE stock stk
          SET stk.stock = stk.stock - 1
          WHERE stk.isbn = old.isbn;
      END IF;

      RETURN NEW;
   END;

$pname$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```